# MariaDB and phpMyAdmin containers communication

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose, mariadb, docker-container

How can i connect to MariaDB in localhost container?

**phpMyAdmin**

```
version: '3'
services:
  pma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    restart: always
```

**MariaDB**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor
    volumes:
      - '.database:/var/lib/mysql'
```

I've tried to connect via PMA to local MariaDB service, but with no luck. I'd like to avoid explicitly link PMA and MariaDB containers, preserving arbitrary server connection (e.g. external server).

Comment: Have you tried using `mariadb` as the hostname in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes I get: #2002 - php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve. Should i add the two containers to the same bridge network or something similar? I 'm new to Docker...

Comment: Yeah try adding them to the same network